# Calling ROS libraries from external CPP

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to call the ROS libraries (shared object .so files) from external CPP program. Below are the ROS libraries, which I copied from `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/` to a sub-directory-

1. /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libkdl_parser.so
2. /opt/ros/indigo/lib/liborocos-kdl.so.1.3.0

I used g++ to compile the main code i.e., `test.cpp`  with following command-

```
g++ -Iinclude -I/usr/include/eigen3 -Lshared -lorocos-kdl -lkdl_parser -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
```

but it is not working, since few more dependencies need to satisfy. Below is the error -

```
test@test:~/Desktop/calll/calling_so$ g++ -Iinclude -I/usr/include/eigen3 -Lshared -lorocos-kdl -lkdl_parser -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
/tmp/ccVP6thR.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x103): undefined reference to `KDL::Tree::Tree(std::string const&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `kdl_parser::treeFromFile(std::string const&, KDL::Tree&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `KDL::Chain::Chain()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to `KDL::Tree::getChain(std::string const&, std::string const&, KDL::Chain&) const'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1f4): undefined reference to `KDL::ChainDynParam::ChainDynParam(KDL::Chain const&, KDL::Vector)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x216): undefined reference to `KDL::JntArray::JntArray(unsigned int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to `KDL::JntSpaceInertiaMatrix::JntSpaceInertiaMatrix(int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x258): undefined reference to `KDL::ChainDynParam::JntToMass(KDL::JntArray const&, KDL::JntSpaceInertiaMatrix&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x271): undefined reference to `KDL::JntSpaceInertiaMatrix::operator()(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x2a6): undefined reference to `KDL::JntSpaceInertiaMatrix::~JntSpaceInertiaMatrix()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x2b5): undefined reference to `KDL::JntArray::~JntArray()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x2c4): undefined reference to `KDL::ChainDynParam::~ChainDynParam()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x2d3): undefined reference to `KDL::Chain::~Chain()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x39b): undefined reference to `KDL::JntSpaceInertiaMatrix::~JntSpaceInertiaMatrix()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x3af): undefined reference to `KDL::JntArray::~JntArray()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x3c3): undefined reference to `KDL::ChainDynParam::~ChainDynParam()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x3d7): undefined reference to `KDL::Chain::~Chain()'
/tmp/ccVP6thR.o: In function `KDL::TreeElement::~TreeElement()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN3KDL11TreeElementD2Ev[_ZN3KDL11TreeElementD5Ev]+0x26): undefined reference to `KDL::Segment::~Segment()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
test@test:~/Desktop/calll/calling_so$
```

Below is `test.cpp`-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <kdl/jntarray.hpp>
#include <kdl/chaindynparam.hpp>
#include <kdl_parser/kdl_parser.hpp>
#include <kdl/jntspaceinertiamatrix.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string urdf_file = "robot.urdf";
    std::string base_link = "base";
    std::string tip_link = "end_effector";

    KDL::Tree tree;
    if (!kdl_parser::treeFromFile(urdf_file, tree)) {
        printf("Failed to construct kdl tree\n");
        return -1;
    }

    KDL::Chain chain;
    if (!tree.getChain(base_link, tip_link, chain))
        printf("Couldn't find chain from %s to %s\n", base_link.c_str(), tip_link.c_str());

    KDL::ChainDynParam dyn(chain, KDL::Vector::Zero());

    KDL::JntArray q(chain.getNrOfJoints()); //dummy value
    KDL::JntSpaceInertiaMatrix H(chain.getNrOfJoints());
    dyn.JntToMass(q, H);

    printf("(0,0) element of Inertia Matrix %f\n", H(0,0));
    return 0;
}
```

The `robot.urdf` is kept along with `test.cpp` and headers are kept in a sub-directory. Below is the directory structure-

```
test@test:~/Desktop/calll/calling_so$ tree
.
├── robot.urdf
├── errors
├── include
│   ├── kdl
│   │   ├── articulatedbodyinertia.hpp
│   │   ├── chaindynparam.hpp
│   │   ├── chain.hpp
│   │   ├── chainidsolver.hpp
│   │   ├── chainidsolver_recursive_newton_euler.hpp
│   │   ├── config.h
│   │   ├── frames.hpp
│   │   ├── frames.inl
│   │   ├── jacobian.hpp
│   │   ├── jntarray.hpp
│   │   ├── jntspaceinertiamatrix.hpp
│   │   ├── joint.hpp
│   │   ├── rigidbodyinertia.hpp
│   │   ├── rotationalinertia.hpp
│   │   ├── segment.hpp
│   │   ├── tree.hpp
│   │   └── utilities
│   │       ├── kdl-config.h
│   │       └── utility.h
│   ├── kdl_parser
│   │   └── kdl_parser.hpp
│   ├── urdf
│   │   ├── model.h
│   │   └── urdfdom_compatibility.h
│   ├── urdf_exception
│   │   └── exception.h
│   └── urdf_model
│       ├── color.h
│       ├── joint.h
│       ├── link.h
│       ├── model.h
│       ├── pose.h
│       ├── types.h
│       └── utils.h
├── shared
│   ├── libkdl_parser.so
│   ├── liborocos-kdl.so -> liborocos-kdl.so.1.3
│   ├── liborocos-kdl.so.1.3 -> liborocos-kdl.so.1.3.0
│   └── liborocos-kdl.so.1.3.0
└── test.cpp

8 directories, 36 files
```

How to resolve this error so that these libraries can be called from an external CPP without using ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247963/calling-ros-libraries-from-external-cpp/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2016-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem. It is little strange at first. Below is the command, I tried and it worked-

```
g++ -L/opt/ros/indigo/lib -Iinclude -I/usr/include/eigen3 test.cpp -lorocos-kdl -lkdl_parser -o test
```

After compiling using above command, make sure the libraries are visible.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2016-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
> ```

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<ModelInterface> ModelInterfaceSharedPtr;
```

This looks more like a C++11 vs Boost problem than anything else. Looks like `urdf::ModelInterfaceSharedPtr` is using `std::shared_ptr` (changed from `boost::shared_ptr`), but your compiler doesn't support it (or support hasn't been enabled).

Note btw that KDL is a stand-alone library: [orocos.org/kdl](http://www.orocos.org/kdl). Only if you want to use the URDF parser(s) do you need to depend on `kdl_parser` (part of `robot_model`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-11-13**:
Hi gvdhoorn, thank you very much. There were some mismatch with the header files, which I have rectified just now. I updated the question. Can you please have a look again? Apologize for the inconvenience.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-14**:
You'll have to figure out which libraries provide those symbols and link those in as well.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-14**:
One other thing: C++11 objects aren't necessarily binary compatible with non-C++11 objects / libraries. If `liborocos-kdl.so` is a C++03 binary, linking as you're doing might not work.

And btw: completely rewriting your question isn't really nice, I can't refer back to the errors you had before.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-11-14**:
Thanks a lot. I understand your concern. I tried compiling without C++11 and got the same errors. AFAIK all `KDL::` are provided by `orocos-kdl` and `kdl_parser::` are provided by `kdl_parser`. Also, I get exactly same errors after removing `-L` and `-l` compiler option. Weird. Isn't it?

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-11-15**:
I solved it. I posted my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40603388/1175065) . Thank you very much.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-15**:
If you posted the solution to an external site, could you please answer your own question here, and include the relevant bits of whatever you posted externally? That keeps this site self-contained. If the external site ever goes down, we don't have an answer here otherwise.